# Web browser image caching with URL image sources

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an API that serves images stored on a remote website to an ASP MVC website.

The website contains a controller with a Get method that returns an image based on the passed file name.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get( string fileName )
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = _apiService.GetImage( fileName );

        using ( MemoryStream streak = new MemoryStream( imageBytes ) )
        {
            return File( streak.ToArray(), string.Format( "image/{0}", Path.GetExtension( fileName ).Replace( ".", "" ) ) );
        }
    }
```

I then use the below code to get display the image on the webpage.

```
<img class="centred-image item-image img-responsive cateogry-image" src="/Images/Get?fileName=football5.jpg" alt="product">
```

However the images don't cache in a browser and get requested/transferred every refresh. How can I change my implementation to allow for image caching?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add this  to your controller:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=3600, VaryByParam="none", Location=OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get( string fileName )
```